# Envelope of Ellipses with Common Major-axis Length

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves

are the envelopes of the following set of ellipses "classical" curves of mathematics, that appear naturally as the solution of a mathematical/physical problem;

$$\mathcal{E}:=\Biggr\{\frac{(x-e)^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{a^2-e^2}-1\ =\ 0\Biggr\},\quad e\in[0,a)$$

the foci of these ellipses have coordinates $(0,0)$ and $(2e,0)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the current version of the question, we can just derive the equation of the [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) in  the usual manner. Using *Mathematica* to do the tedious algebra on my behalf, we obtain:

```
First[Factor[GroebnerBasis[{(x - e)^2/a^2 + y^2/(a^2 - e^2) == 1,
                            D[(x - e)^2/a^2 + y^2/(a^2 - e^2) - 1, e] == 0}, {x, y, a}, e]]]
   (4 a^2 - x^2 - 4 a y) (4 a^2 - x^2 + 4 a y) (x^2 + y^2)
```

where we see the envelope has three components: an isolated point at $(0,0)$ and **two parabolas** (which are certainly "classical curves of mathematics" as the OP asks), $y=\pm\dfrac{x^2}{4a}\mp a$:

```
With[{a = 1}, 
     Show[ParametricPlot[Table[{e + a Cos[t], Sqrt[a^2 - e^2] Sin[t]}, {e, 0, a, a/24}],
                         {t, 0, 2 π}], 
          Plot[{x^2/(4 a) - a, a - x^2/(4 a)}, {x, -2, 2}, 
               PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], ColorData[97, 3]]], 
          AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, Automatic}]]
```

[image: ellipses and their envelope]

Comment: Beautiful. This looks like an eye.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the "envelope" of the $\mathcal{E}_1$ set of ellipses?

---

[image: Ellipses]

          

<sup>$\mathcal{E}_1$: $a=1$; $e=0,0.1,\ldots,0.9,1$.</sup>

---

Added after OP change, now $\mathcal{E}$:

---

[image: Ellipses2]

          

<sup>$a=2$; $e=0,0.1,\ldots,a$.</sup>

---

Comment: I will delete the $\mathcal{E}_1$ part of the question; I had added that as the "ellipses in standard position" counterpart to the $\mathcal{E}_2$ set of ellipses that have their left focus in the origin and the right one on the x-axis.